# External C/C++ library not printing in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

I'm calling a C++ external library from C#. Return works, however `printf()` does not print data in the console window. Why does it happen? Am I doing something wrong?

Even when I call `DisplayHelloFromDLL` without assigning its return to variable x, printed text does not show on the screen.

C++:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

extern "C"
{
__declspec(dllexport) char * DisplayHelloFromDLL()
 {
     printf ("Hello from DLL !\n");
     return "Something";

 }
}
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;



class HelloWorld
{

    [DllImport("Hello.dll", EntryPoint = "DisplayHelloFromDLL")]
    public static extern string DisplayHelloFromDLL();

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is C# program");
        string x = DisplayHelloFromDLL();
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no C code shown. You mean C++.

Comment: Yes, sorry I will edit the question. However, I dont get why somebody down voted it.

Comment: You handle a `char*` return type that way on the C# side. Your code attempts to deallocate the pointer calling `CoTaskMemFree`. Declare the return type as `IntPtr` and get a string with `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan actually returning data works good. However 'printf()' in C does not print "Hello from DLL" in Console.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How it can not work? It is printing "Something" on the screen. Are we talking about the same things?

Comment: I explained why it doesn't work. You don't seem to care about undefined behaviour. If it looks like it works, then that's good enough for you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think you did not read the question. I'm talking about 'printf()' in C++ code, why it does not print data in the console.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm telling you about another problem in your code. Are you interested in learning something you don't know, or not?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK, thank you for sharing this knowledge. I appreciate it. However that is not the problem, and your answer does not solve it anyway. I'm not a C/C++ developer.

Comment: Since you recognise that you don't understand the issue I describe, wouldn't it be sensible to try to absorb this knowledge that you don't have? I do not understand people that are not interested in learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this thread (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5da6cdb2-bc2b-4fff-8adf-752b32143dae/printf-from-dll-in-console-app-in-visual-studio-c-2010-express-does-not-output-to-console-window?forum=Vsexpressvcs) the Visual Studio hosting process that exists when debugging is the reason why the console output from the DLL does not make its way to your console.

A simple way to check this is to run the executable directly rather than via the IDE's debugger. If that does confirm that this is the case then you can disable the hosting process if you wish, as described in the linked thread.

Your code has another couple of problems:

```
[DllImport("Hello.dll", EntryPoint = "DisplayHelloFromDLL")]
public static extern string DisplayHelloFromDLL();
```

The default p/invoke calling convention is `stdcall` but the default C++ calling convention is `cdecl`. Your C# p/invoke therefore uses the wrong calling convention. You will need to change one of the declarations to resolve this.

And declaring the return type as `string` means that the marshaller will attempt to deallocate the returned pointer by calling `CoTaskMemFree`. The C string was not allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc` so this is undefined behaviour. You should declare the return type as `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` to obtain the string, remembering that the C++ code returns a literal which should not (indeed cannot) be deallocated. Alternatively, use one of the various other ways to return a string that are perhaps a little clearer in the way memory ownership is determined.

Comment: Actually this helped: "A simple way to check this is to run the executable directly rather than via the IDE's debugger. If that does confirm that this is the case then you can disable the hosting process if you wish, as described in the linked thread.". It works, however I have to start this app from other cmd window.

Answer (score -1):

I think, your Problem is that the DLL has no console assigned to it - it should not know the C#-Console. Maybe, you can try to pass a reference to your C#-Console-Object to your "DisplayHelloFromDLL"-Function.
But I never tried it - I do not know, how to Access/use the C#-Console-Object from a C/C++ DLL.

Answer (score -1):

Your C external library might not have access to the any output console. You can use following functions for writing in to an output console.

[AllocConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx)

[GetSTDHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231(v=vs.85).aspx)

[WriteConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401(v=vs.85).aspx)